# How to move physical cursor using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pyautogui

I was creating a log-in script for a website when I came across a little problem.

I managed to make the script work but only when ran on a certain laptop. I want to make it executable on any computer, but the problem is I can't find something that moves my physical cursor to a specified element with timing, kind of like pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, time) except instead of moving to specific coordinates with timing, moves to a specific element with timing.

I kept coming across action chains and at first I thought it worked, but it doesn't move the actual physical cursor like pyautogui does.

Any possible solutions?

Comment: Can you confirm the url, and also show us your code attempts, so someone can recreate your problem? While selenium doesn't move physical mouse, tell us what you are trying to achieve, and maybe you will receive a solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Actions API

As per the specification [**Actions API**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-actions) is the low-level interface for providing virtualized device input actions to the web browser. [*Actions API*](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/) provides granular control over whatsoever designated input devices can do. Through this interface Selenium psupports three kinds of input sources:

1. A [key input](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/keyboard/) for keyboard devices.
2. A pointer input for a [mouse](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/mouse/), [pen](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/pen/) or touch devices.
3. [Wheel inputs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/wheel/) for scroll wheel devices.

Using this API individual action commands of specific inputs can be constructed and chained them together to be performed all at once.

---

### Conclusion

So in short all your requirements involving moving the physical cursor to a specified element along with timing, just like `pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, time)` etc can be easily simulated using this Actions API.